# Unable to get Postgresql commands to work in terminal

Tags: macos, postgresql

After installing Postgresql by dragging folder into my applications folder I am unable to get commands to work in the terminal and unable to add the path so that is shows up using the command $ echo $PATH.

Postgres starts in the terminal using the elephant icon on the system tray and selecting "open psql" so I believe it installed correctly.

I tried adding all different combinations of the following lines to my .bash_profile

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

and finally

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

After each attempt I ran $ source $HOME/.bash_profile and then checked path and/or tried $psql $ which psql to no avail.

Also tried adding lines to .bashrc, .profile and .zshrc without luck.

The path to the executable commands bin folder in the app (psql, createdb, createlang, etc..) is

```
$ /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

running OSX 10.9.1
- posted question on stackoverflow but may be more appropriate here...??

adding my .bash_profile below-----

```
PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -lahG"
alias finder="open `pwd`"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=HBfxcxdxbxegedabagacadexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-   2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error on this line:

```
export LSCOLORS=HBfxcxdxbxegedabagacadexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-   2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

This will set both the `LSCOLORS` and `PATH` variables.

I think that the last part of this line is an error. Removing it should fix your problem.

By setting the `PATH` variable here it will remove the previous changes that you have made because you are explicitly setting the value without reference to `$PATH`.

The last `export` at the end of the `export LSCOLORS=HBfxcxdxbxegedabagacadexport` command should probably be removed too.

Comment: I returned a line after the LSCOLORS line and then added :$PATH after the end of the the PATH=/usr/local/bin..... line. It worked THANK YOU!

Comment: :) You're welcome, I'm pleased you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I assume that you are trying to run `psql` from the standard terminal and that you have installed PostgresSQL using the standard OS X Graphical installer [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/).

On OS X, `psql` is installed in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/` and the shortcut in launchpad simply runs this executable.

So you need to add `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/` to your path and then you should be ok.

Edit: Also, see question on Database Administrators [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/how-to-run-psql-on-mac-os-x).

Edit: It seems that you have actually installed the `Postgres.app`. In that case `psql` is indeed located in `/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` and adding the following to your `~/.bash_profile` should make it work from terminal:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH
```

Comment: thanks for the advice but adding that path did not work. I looked in the path and there is no PostgreSQL directory in the /Library. I did verify that the executables do exist within the path /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin. I installed PG by downloading zip file, extracting and then copying and pasting folder into applications directory. I am following the directions at this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

Comment: Try adding `PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH to your `~/.bash_profile`. Note the position of the quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you had installed it using the graphical installer. If the above works, I will update the answer.

Comment: No luck that time either. I tried inserting lines                           export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH and then PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH (without export at beginning of the line)

Comment: @JimmyF Does it work if you run `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH` within the terminal window?

Comment: No, here is what it shows when I run command                         Jimmy$ PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH
Jimmy$ psql
-bash: psql: command not found

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` then show?

Comment: Jimmy$ echo $PATH
/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin

Comment: And that's after you run `PATH=...`? That's very strange

Comment: Please can you just try to run the following and post the results `echo $PATH; PATH=/opt:$PATH; echo $PATH`? Just as a sanity check!

Comment: Jimmy$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Jimmy$ echo $PATH
/opt:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Ok, and `PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH; echo $PATH`?

Comment: ok...now this is working Jimmy$ PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin":$PATH
Jimmy$ echo $PATH
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin                 the commands are not recognized though

Comment: but `~/.bash_profile` still does't work with `PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH`?

Comment: Is it really `Postgres.app` or `Postgres93.app`

Comment: for me it is `Postgres93.app` but we may have installed different things!

Comment: And can you run it using `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql' or `/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql'?

Comment: For me it's Postgres93.app and the line export PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH does not have it show up using $echo $PATH even after running $ source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: is there anything else in your `.bash_profile` or just the path update?

Comment: PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -lahG"
alias finder="open `pwd`"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH

Comment: export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=HBfxcxdxbxegedabagacadexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Jimmy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Comment: it looks like you are explicitly setting the PATH after the `export LSCOLORS` line...

Comment: try putting `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"` right at the end

Comment: commented out the msql line and it didn't work, How would I get around explicitly setting the path using the export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Can you add the whole .bash_profile file to your original question? I think it will be clearer! I think this is the problem now...

Comment: just added it, I put the current version that doesn't have quotation marks on the Postgres line

Comment: Ok, I think that the quotes were definitely not the issue now. I have posted a new answer.